# gravity form: stipe credit card verification Failed. Getting this Error: Unable to authorize card. No response from Stripe.js

Tags: stripe-payments, gravity-forms-plugin

After i filled card details and click submit i'm getting this error "Unable to authorize card. No response from Stripe.js" could someone tell me what im doing wrong why this is coming
Thanks

Comment: How you are sending the data.